# How can I perform same action on two buttons on different controller in Ios

Tags: ios

`I am using Timer in containing app which i am displaying on widget (Today Extension).Now i have requirement that i can start and stop the timer from today extension If I start timer from today extension using on button click then it start and stop then stop.`
 Same thing from containing app.But both work together means communicate with each other.If i stop from today extension then timer will also stop in containing app same with Start.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code in some backend class and only fire it from your controllers.

Comment: How can I do that.I am a beginner in Ios. So plz provide an example if it is possible.Thanks